# Accessing ViewContext from class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to access `ViewContext` from class library? I am in need of getting names of current View and Controller's action. I added both `System.Web.dll` and `System.Web.Mvc` in my class library project but still unable to find a way to get what I require. 
Although I can access current context using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Are you wondering how to do this from a static context? What exactly are you trying to achieve? This seems like a bad design.

Comment: actually i am using nhibernate events for automatic audit trailing and for this besing details like who changed what and when i am also in need of details about on which view or form record was created or edited. So in the audit trail row will be something like View|Action|UserName|DateChanged. And yes this nhibernate code is placed inside a sepearate dll

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access current route information like this:

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Comment: For anyone like me coming to this answer, you can now access the routedata directly from the context: `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]` seems to be more accurate than doing with the above way

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[‌​"controller"]` approach does not work in static class.